# Uninitialized constant from the superclass

Tags: ruby, uninitialized-constant

I have a `FUU` constante inside `Foo` and `Foo2` classes, and in order to DRY my code, I moved a method inside the `BaseStuff` superclass. Just like this:

```
class BaseStuff
  def to_s
    FUU
  end
end

class Foo < BaseStuff
  FUU = "ok"
end

class Foo2 < BaseStuff
  FUU = "ok2"
end
```

But my problem is that, after:

```
a = Foo.new
puts a.to_s
```

I get this error:

> NameError: uninitialized constant BaseStuff::FUU

Is there a best practice to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class BaseStuff
  FUU = nil
  def to_s
    self.class::FUU
  end
end

class Foo < BaseStuff
  FUU = "ok"
end

class Foo2 < BaseStuff
  FUU = "ok2"
end

a = Foo.new
puts a.to_s # => ok

puts Foo2.new.to_s # => ok2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class Foo < BaseStuff
  ::FUU = "ok"
end
```

Comment: Waw, works well! However this may be tricky to use in my case, 'cause I'm adding this constant dynamically. Thanks anyway.